# Check if value is over 21 chars

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to check if the text field have over 21 characters. If it have over 21 characters, then show the error message. The code below shows how I have made it so far. Everything works fine but I'm stuck on this small problem. How can I solve this problem?

```
$('input[name="textfield-googleplus"]').keyup(function() {
    $('.input-error').remove();

    var input_value = $(this).val();
    var only_numeric = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
    var max_twentyone = /[0-9]{21}/;


    if(input_value != '' && !only_numeric.test(input_value)) {
        $(this).after('<span class="input-error">Ditt profil-ID får enbart innehålla siffror</span>');

    } else if(input_value != '' && !max_twentyone.test(input_value)) {
        $(this).after('<span class="input-error">Ditt profil-ID får enbart innehålla 21 siffror</span>');
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about `$(this).val().length <= 21` What you check with the regex is if there are exactly 21 digits as a substring in the string (^ and $ mean starts with and ends with). however you could of course also rewrite the regex so it supports all the other characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regex is not necessary here. Just check `(input_value.length > 21)`.

Comment: Many thanks! Your answer solved my whole problem :) I'll mark it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (typeof input_value == "string") {
    if (input_value.length > 21) { // is more than 21 chars

    }
}
```

i only through in the first if cause i wasn't sure if you intend that to always be string